# Верны ли запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

«Когда из-за холода сосуды сужаются, кровоток уменьшается и ноги начинают мёрзнуть».

Верна ли пунктуация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, всё верно. Конец фразы целиком следствие из придаточной части, ноги начинают мёрзнуть **тоже из-за сужения сосудов.**

Comment: Когда из-за холода сосуды сужаются, кровоток уменьшается, а вот ноги начинают мёрзнуть по причине уменьшения кровотока, поэтому  придаточное предложение относится только к первой части сложносочиненного предложения, а значит, запятая нужна

Comment: @виктор1799: не согласен. Причина всё равно первая.